# Why are these definitions of the Law of large numbers the same?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

I have learnt the following definition of the law of large numbers:

> Theorem 17.4 (Law of Large Numbers). Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with common finite expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]=\mu$ for all $i$. Then, their partial sums $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ satisfy
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n} S_n-\mu\right|<\varepsilon\right] \rightarrow 1 \quad \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty,
> $$
> for every $\varepsilon>0$.

I am having trouble connecting this to the other common definition of the law of large numbers, which is that "the average of the results of independent identical trials approaches the trial's expected value the more trials we take", for the following single reason:

the theorem seems to state that the sum of $n$ **random variables** divided by $n$ approaches the expected value of one of them, whereas the other definition states that the average of any **specific values which said random variables assume** approaches the expected value of these random variables. I am seeing a difference between these because one talks about random variables, the other talks about a set of possible values which they assume. I would be very appreciative if anyone could explain why these definitions are the same.

Comment: The convergence takes place in probability, which is said in 17.4. Sometimes called "weak law of large numbers". The strong law of large numbers requires finite variance and convergence of a certain series for $\frac{1}{n}S_n\to \mu$ to hold with probability $1$.

Comment: For strong law of large numbers it also suffices if $X_1$ is integrable ($E|X_1|<\infty$).

Comment: You can write $\frac1nS_n$ as $\bar X_n$ so this is really about the average.  

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left[\left|\bar X_n-\mu\right|<\varepsilon\right] = 1$ for all $\varepsilon >0$ is the **weak** law of large numbers.  

If instead you look at the sequence $\bar X_1, \bar X_2, \bar X_3, \ldots$ then $\mathbb{P}\left[\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\bar X_n-\mu) =0\right] = 1$ is the **strong** law of large numbers, and harder to prove if all you know is $E[|X_i|]$ is finite.